# MVC .NET - Normalized Data Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new to MVC and am having trouble trying to work with a normalized data model (just a list of movies and their cast list). I have the following three data models setup (simplified), which is a basic many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Movie
{
        public int Movie_Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Director { get; set; }
        public DateTime Release_Date { get; set; }

        public MovieCast movieCast { get; set; }
}

public class MovieCast
{
        public int Movie_Actor_Id { get; set; }
        public int Movie_Id { get; set; }
        public int Actor_Id { get; set; }

        public Movie movie { get; set; }
        public Actor actor { get; set; }

}

public class Actor
{
        public int Actor_Id { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

        public MovieCast movieCast { get; set; }
}
```

I'm looking to display the entire list of actors from the MovieCast controller. In the Index.cshtml file I have the following

```
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movie_Id)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Actor_Id)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.actor.First_Name)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
```

The final DisplayNameFor is giving me an error saying that "MovieCast" does not contain a definition for "actor", even though it's clearly declared in the model.

Does anyone have any ideas, or do I need to rethink the solution??

Comment: What does your action code look like?  I'm guessing you didn't create all the instances and 'actor' is 'null'

Comment: In it's simplest form, it looks like this:

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new List<MovieCast>());
        }

Comment: If that is the case, you aren't creating an instance of the actor, so it is returning `null`, if it is `null` no values can be pulled out of it.

Comment: [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UmdhRf) is a working example you can use to see where something might have gone wrong.

Comment: would throw a null reference exception if it is null... i think

Comment: @Steve true, but without actual code, it could be something as simple as in correct casing.  When mvc renders the errors aren't always what you would think would be thrown.

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing this... I think you should use a List<MovieCast> inside your Movie class. I understand that you're doing it with a normalized style, like SQL... but I don't think any real code would be like this.

I need that you should rethink the solution.

Comment: I mean, when you have a situation like "X has many Y", then "X has a list of Y inside itself".

Also, an object of type Actor belongs to only one MovieCast.... i mean, you should really rethink your solution. Object oriented is very different from the relational model, I can see that your classes could make perfect sense in a relational environment.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that a Movie has a MovieCast, which is a List of Actors who participated in the film.

Also, I would never use a relational-like structure in my classes... I prefer to use a more object-oriented structure.

I would simplify it to:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Director {get;set;}
    public DateTime ReleaseDate {get;set;}

    public List<Actor> Cast {get;set;}

}

public enum Gender {
    Male, Female
}


public class Actor {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}
```

And in my view, I would do something like this:

```
@model List<Movie>


@foreach (var movie in Model){

<h1>@movie.Title</h1>

<h3>Movie Details:</h3>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Director:</td><td>@movie.Director</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Release Date:</td><td>@movie.ReleaseDate</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h3>Cast</h3>

<ul>
    @foreach(var actor in movie.Cast)
    {
    <li>
        @actor.FirstName
    </li>
    }
</ul>

}
```

Not sure if it compiles, but give it a try :D